# Change vehicle profile on viaroute request in OSRM?

Tags: api, request, openstreetmap, osrm

I am developing an application based on OSRM that provides distances in kms and minutes starting from a list of addresses.

I am using the request "viaroute" to get back the desired information.
This is an example of request:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=52.503033,13.420526&loc=52.516582,13.429290&instructions=true
```

The response message contains the tag "total_time" (representing the time needed to reach the destination point starting from the source point). This value is computed by using a set of parameter characterizing the vehicle type.
I would like to change the profile of the vehicle type (for instance: truck) to compute the "total_time" considering the maximum speed allowed for vehicle type used (ex: set the max speed in highway street to 110 km/h and not 130 km/h).

Someone could help me for this issue?

Thanks in advance
Fabio

Comment: They don't provide such as this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a single OSRM instance can currently only support a single profile. That's why it is not possible to specify the profile via the API. Also, the official demo instance at router.project-osrm.org only supports the "car" profile.

If you need other profiles then take a look at the various other [routing services for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#End_users:_Routing_software). There are also various third-party OSRM instances with different profiles available, but I don't know any instance with a truck profile.